# Difference between &.each and .each for arrays in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

```
irb(main):007:0> %w[1 2 3 4 5]&.each { |a| puts a }
1
2
3
4
5
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
irb(main):008:0> %w[1 2 3 4 5].each { |a| puts a }
1
2
3
4
5
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Both `&.each` and `.each` seems to give the same results

[ruby-doc](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-26) doesn't seem to have anything regarding this functionality

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`&.each` is an operator and a method. `each` is only one method.

> &., called “safe navigation operator”, allows to skip method call when
>   receiver is nil. It returns nil and doesn't evaluate method's
>   arguments if the call is skipped.

So, if the receiver is `nil` (which isn't the case in your example) it'll just return `nil` because it doesn't respond to `each`:

```
nil&.each
# nil
```

Otherwise, invoking any non-defined method in an object throws a `NoMethodError`. And is what you'll get in your second example:

```
nil.each
# ...
# NoMethodError (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass)
```

The documentation about the safe navigation operator is in the [Calling Methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Safe+navigation+operator) documentation. While for `each` it's in [Array](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-each).